# pod spec lint: Attempt to read non existent folder

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

Trying to lint a **local** pod spec

```
$ pod spec lint MyPod.podspec
```

I'm getting

> [!] Attempt to read non existent folder `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/MyPod`.

I checked `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/` where I didn't find my podspec indeed,
but I found it in `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Local Podspecs/`

**What can cause this and/or how can I debug ?**

---

For info here is my pod spec

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "MyPod"
    s.version      = "0.0.1"
    s.summary      = "A pretty cool pod"
    s.author       = { "Me" => "me@home.net" }
    s.license      = 'MIT'
    s.homepage     = "http://www.mypod.net"
    s.source       = { :path => "." }
    s.source_files = '*.{h,m}'
    s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'
    s.requires_arc = true
end
```

`:path` seems to cause the trouble, `:git` works

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385329/cocoapod-attempt-to-read-non-existent-folder-private-tmp-cocoapods-lint-pods , but neither of these have a satisfactory answer, imo.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused by commented `s.source` line as I was testing it before with local podspec and sources. When you'll commit your podspec to the repo make sure to run `pod repo update`

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you have not yet pushed your podspec's targeted tags to your origin/repo. I assume the same might also be true if you are targeting a non-existent git, branch, etc.