# Attempt to read non existent folder `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/

Tags: ios, cocoapods

AM getting this while validating pod spec:

```
Attempt to read non existent folder `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Test
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 14):

You need to run `git tag 'x.x.x'` and `git push --tags` before `pod spec lint`.

Comment: This error `fatal: Remote branch x.x.x not found in upstream origin` will be solved using the above solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

Try running your command with `--verbose` to see more helpful error messages:

```
pod spec lint --verbose
...
fatal: Remote branch 0.4.8 not found in upstream origin
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This error is caused by git checkout failed. In my case the tag was not pushed to server side. You can find the exact cause by looking at your error message.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by running pod install again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the first '/' so it should looks like:

```
'private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Test'
```

You should add to your .podspec file the paths with reference to the .pocspec file location.

For example, if your folders look like:

[image]

So your `.podspec` paths should refer to:

```
s.source_files = 'PodTestPublicProject/*.{h,m}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, when the referred git-tag was not already pushed to upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to run either `pod spec lint` or `pod trunk push` without specifying the podspec file.

So try passing the name of the file to the command (replace `NAME` accordingly):

```
$ pod spec lint NAME.podspec

$ pod trunk push NAME.podspec
```

See [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the directory where executing 'pod install' has special character, also catch the error: Attempt to read non existent folder
Source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2649